# How to use nested if-else in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, nested

I am doing calculator and I wrote codes if user doesn't enter value to num1 and num2 it will give message to the screen and I did it with if-else. It is working for num1 and operator but not num2. How can I fix it?

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please enter data to number 1 ")
                TextBox1.Focus()
                Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Else
                Label1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText
            End If
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please enter data to number 2")
                TextBox2.Focus()
                Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Else
                Label1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be something like:

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter data to number 1 ")
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
    ' Seperate the conditions because TextBox1 and TextBox2 can both be empty, so an ElseIf will not handle it
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter data to number 2")
        TextBox2.Focus()
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
Else ' Neither of them (so TextBox1 and TextBox2 won't be empty)
    Label1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText
End If
```

This will popup a message when the user leaves TextBox1 empty or TextBox2 empty, if he doesn't leave any of the two empty, the `Else` will kick in.

For more informations about conditions in VB.NET, take a look here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/if-vbnet

Comment: You're right, but he's a beginner so I avoided adding code.

Comment: you mean that? Private Sub textbox1_leave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            TextBox1.Focus()
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Return
        Else
            Label1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: and am I gonna do private sub for textbox2_leave and combobox?